# What is the meaning of to have been and founding?

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense, present-perfect

> He is the first North Korean leader to *have been* born after the country's *founding.*

<sup>([Wikipedia: Kim Jong-un](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Jong-un))</sup>

What is the meaning of to have been

And founding in this context.?

Answer (score 2):

"Founding" is another word for "foundation": the act of founding the country.

"To have been born" is the construction sometimes called the *past infinitive*. "To be born" would also be possible here: as often with tenses in English, there are various possibilities, none of them wrong, which give a slightly different view of what is said. The use of the past infinitive "to have been born" focusses the sentence temporally on a later point, presumably when he is an adult.